# Route playback using ionic cordova google map

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I already had the set of `gps coordinates` and using those `gps coordinates` to display the **vehicle** where it was travelled at that time. I have to show the vehicle movement on `google map`  as like a **video**.
I had build an vehicle tracking application, so for my application i have to show where the vehicles were travelled at a certain period of time. so for that i need to do a route playback, kindly help me to do this.

Comment: What is your question? Write it.

Comment: Please provide what you have done so far, Stackoverflow is not the place where you will get project development from community. First you need to try out stuff and if something is not working or you are struck somewhere then you should ask question on SO. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask